# How do you create a password protected registration form that checks the password against a database table before submit?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, password-protection

I have a php registration form and one of the fields on the form is a password field and I want the form to check the password against a database table list of passwords before allowing the form to submit the user's info. So pretty much the user needs a password to register. I have been looking for a solution for this and have not come across one.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You would be exposing your authentication system in a big way as someone could keep entering passwords to see which ones were in your database...

Comment: @foxbeefly its part of a promotion where a couple hundred of passwords are mailed out and I only want those people to register and take part in the promotion.

Comment: After they use the code to register, I would have them submit their info to the database along with the code they used and create a unique field based on that code so that way it can only be used once upon registration

Comment: Ah so more a promotional code than a password.

Comment: @foxbeefly yeah pretty much, I just wasn't sure how to word it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="promo" required>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$promo_codes = ['code1', 'code2'];
if(in_array($_POST['promo'], $promo_codes) {
    //in array, continue
} else {
    //not in array, exit gracefully
}
```

Basically create a form entry for the promo code in the html and something like the above to validate the promo codes.

Comment: would that require me to list all of the codes in the

 $promo_codes = ['code1', 'code2'];

section? I have all the codes stored currently in a separate table in my DB

Comment: You can read it from a database, a CSV, anything really. Just select them all from the table. You do know how to use PDO or mysqli to retrieve them right?

Comment: something like:

$mysql_query = sprintf("SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code=%s", GetSQLValueString($code, "text"));

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
<form>
<input name="username" />
<input name="email" />

<input name="promo_code" id="promo" />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>

<script>
 + use jQuery to fire off an AJAX call with the value in the #promo input of the form
 + if a match is found in the database enable the form or the button on the form so that they can register
 + delete the promo code from the database once the registration takes place
</script>
```